# How to convert "Y/m/d h:i A" format date and time to timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

how can i convert `2016/02/12 09:00 PM` format date and time to Unix timestamp.Thanks in advance

Comment: try this `$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i A', '2016/02/12 09:00 PM',new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d->getTimestamp();`

Answer (score 0):

Have You Tried the `strtotime()` function.

Take a look in detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php